# In PHP SELECT statement returns true, update another table with its primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables (`art` and `artlocation`) that have three columns (`series`, `style` and `location`) in common. What I want to do is determine if all three fields are an exact match in BOTH tables then `UPDATE` one of the tables (as a foreign key) with the primary key of the other.

This is the query that I ran to determine if there is a match:

```
SELECT * FROM 'artlocation'  
  JOIN 'art' ON artlocation.series = art.series
  WHERE artlocation.style = art.style
    AND artlocation.location = art.location;
```

What I want to do is get the primary key from any match from the "artlocation" table and update the "art" table foreign key field. BUT I cannot FIGURE this out :(

Please help... thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. Also, the [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete. Please include table creation statements, test data (in the form of an `INSERT` statement) and the desired results of the `SELECT` statement (if what you have isn't working), and post-`UPDATE`.

Comment: And that query doesn't return the primary key you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want a multiple table [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html). You can use a JOIN in the table portion of the `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE art
  JOIN artlocation ON art.series = artlocation.series 
                  AND art.style = artlocation.style 
                  AND art.location = artlocation.location
  SET art.location = artlocation.id
```

Comment: OMG thank you from the BOTTOM of my heart!! This worked like a charm!

Comment: Always remember to check the manual. It often has the information you seek.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you mean correctly i think it'll works

```
Update art 
    LEFT JOIN artlocation al ON al.series = art.series 
SET [ Your Columns Here ]  
WHERE al.style = art.style AND al.location = art.location
```